# How to write data to characteristic on button click?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an android app that uses BLE. I am trying to write data to a characteristic on button click but unable to do that.

I have a service which is having two characteristic and out of those two characteristic I am writing data on one on button click.

**Ble class where I have defined writeDatatoCharacteristic**

```
/* set new value for particular characteristic */
public void writeDataToCharacteristic(final BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch, final byte[] value) {

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null || ch == null) {
        return;
    }

    // first set it locally....
    ch.setValue(value);


    // ... and then "commit" changes to the peripheral
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(ch);
}
```

**xml file for button**

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonPlay"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivRestart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClickWrite"/>
```

**Main Activity where I am calling the write data to characteristic function**

```
public class Tens_modes extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String LOGTAG = "BLETEST";
private final String TARGET = "CC2650 SensorTag";
private BleWrapper mBleWrapper = null;
private mSensorState mState;
private String gattList = "";
private TextView mTv;

private enum mSensorState {IDLE, ACC_ENABLE, ACC_READ};

public final static UUID
        UUID_ACC_SERV = fromString("FFE0"),
        UUID_ACC_DATA = fromString("f000aa11-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"),
        UUID_ACC_CONF = fromString("FFE9"), // 0: disable, 1: enable
        UUID_ACC_PERI = fromString("f000aa13-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"); // Period in tens of milliseconds




private ImageButton play;
private ImageButton pause;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tens_modes);

    play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlay);
    pause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPause);


    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    //Ble stuff

    mBleWrapper = new BleWrapper(this, new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null()
    {

        @Override
        public void uiDeviceFound(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] record)
        {

            Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiDeviceFound: " + device.getName() + ", " + rssi + ", " + record.toString());
            if (device.getName().equals(TARGET))
            {
                if (!mBleWrapper.connect(device.getAddress()))
                {
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiDeviceFound: Problem connecting to remote device.");
                }
            }
            //stopScan();
        }
        @Override
        public void uiDeviceConnected(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device)
        {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiDeviceConnected: State = " + mBleWrapper.getAdapter().getState());

        }

        @Override
        public void uiDeviceDisconnected(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiDeviceDisconnected: State = " + mBleWrapper.getAdapter().getState());
        }

        @Override
        public void uiAvailableServices(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothDevice device, List<BluetoothGattService> services)
        {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic c;
            BluetoothGattDescriptor d;

            for (BluetoothGattService service : services)
            {
                String serviceName = BleNamesResolver.resolveUuid(service.getUuid().toString());
                Log.e(LOGTAG, serviceName);
                gattList += serviceName + "\n";

                mBleWrapper.getCharacteristicsForService(service);
            }

            // enable services
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "uiAvailableServices: Enabling services");
            c = gatt.getService(UUID_ACC_SERV).getCharacteristic(UUID_ACC_CONF);

            mBleWrapper.writeDataToCharacteristic(c, new byte[] {0300000000AA});

            //mState = mSensorState.ACC_ENABLE;



            // set notification on characteristic
            //Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiAvailableServices: Setting notification");
            //c = gatt.getService(UUID_IRT_SERV).getCharacteristic(UUID_IRT_DATA);
            //mBleWrapper.setNotificationForCharacteristic(c, true);

            // enable notification on descriptor
            //d = c.getDescriptor(UUID_CCC_DESC);
            //d.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            //gatt.writeDescriptor(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void uiCharacteristicForService( BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                                   BluetoothDevice device,
                                                   BluetoothGattService service,
                                                   List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> chars)
        {
            super.uiCharacteristicForService(gatt, device, service, chars);
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic c : chars)
            {
                String charName = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(c.getUuid().toString());
                Log.d(LOGTAG, charName);
                gattList += "Characteristic: " + charName + "\n";
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void uiSuccessfulWrite(  BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                          BluetoothDevice device,
                                          BluetoothGattService service,
                                          BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch,
                                          String description)
        {
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic c;

            super.uiSuccessfulWrite(gatt, device, service, ch, description);
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiSuccessfulWrite");

            switch (mState)
            {
                case ACC_ENABLE:
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiSuccessfulWrite: Reading acc");
                    c = gatt.getService(UUID_ACC_SERV).getCharacteristic(UUID_ACC_DATA);
                    mBleWrapper.requestCharacteristicValue(c);
                    mState = mSensorState.ACC_READ;
                    break;

                case ACC_READ:
                    Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiSuccessfulWrite: state = ACC_READ");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void uiFailedWrite(  BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                      BluetoothDevice device,
                                      BluetoothGattService service,
                                      BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch,
                                      String description)
        {
            super.uiFailedWrite(gatt, device, service, ch, description);
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiFailedWrite");
        }

        @Override
        public void uiNewValueForCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                                BluetoothDevice device,
                                                BluetoothGattService service,
                                                BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch,
                                                String strValue,
                                                int intValue,
                                                byte[] rawValue,
                                                String timestamp)
        {
            super.uiNewValueForCharacteristic(gatt, device, service, ch, strValue, intValue, rawValue, timestamp);
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "uiNewValueForCharacteristic");
            for (byte b:rawValue)
            {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "Val: " + b);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void uiGotNotification(  BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                          BluetoothDevice device,
                                          BluetoothGattService service,
                                          BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
        {
            super.uiGotNotification(gatt, device, service, characteristic);
            String ch = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(characteristic.getUuid().toString());

            Log.d(LOGTAG,  "uiGotNotification: " + ch);
        }
    });

}

public void onClickWrite(View v){
    if(mBleWrapper != null) {
        // enable services
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "uiAvailableServices: Enabling services");
            byte[] value = new byte[1];
            value[0] = (byte)21;
            mBleWrapper.writeDataToCharacteristic(UUID_ACC_CONF, new byte[] {0300000000AA});

    }
}
```

I want to write 0300000000AA as a value to characteristic but don't know how to do that. Searching for it from last 4,5 hours but didn;t get anything useful

Please if anyone can help me with this and tell me what I am doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: Does any information get written when the button press occurs? (what actually seems to be the problem? Can you not write (any) data? or is the data wrong? etc. You aren't actually stating what the 'exact' problem/question is.

Comment: The exact problem is it is not taking the data in the way I am giving it. Whenever I write 0300000000AA as a value it is not taking it. It shows a red line below AA in the given number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you. (well be a start, I'm not sure about encoding)

```
byte[] temp;
//This will at least compile, however I don't know if that is what you want, strings in java are unicode, not ascii. you might have to convert to your desired encoding
temp = "0300000000AA".getBytes();
mBleWrapper.writeDataToCharacteristic(UUID_ACC_CONF, temp );
```